# Android horizontal layout overlapping edittext

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development and I would like to have a full screen edit text with some buttons below it. When the keyboard appears, the buttons will float above the keyboard and the edittext will end above the buttons.

[image]

This is what I've currently done, as you can see, the edit text is current behind the buttons. How can I make the edit text ends above the layout of the button?

This is my view setup

[image]

XML File

[image]

Comment: Show your xml file

Comment: @Vickyexpert I've added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using a `RelativeLayout`, right? If so, try to add this inside your `EditText`:

```
android:layout_above="@id/theIDOfYourButton"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thats because your button is inside a LinearLayout. Try to give the layout an ID (android:id="@+id/linearLayoutWithButton") and set the layout_above id to "@id/linearLayoutWithButton

Comment: Seems like my LinearLayout starts all the way from the top and after doing that, edittext seems to be out of the view. How do I get my layout to say take up 10% of the screen space at the bottom?

Comment: That's because of your layout_height value in your LinearLayout. Replace it by this:
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Thanks for your help! Finally be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Please insert this code in your xml code.
edit as per requirement.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

In your menifest.xml
for this activity add below tag:

**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**

Hope this work!!